# Do internal forces of an atom lead to motion?

Tags: forces, classical-mechanics, atomic-physics

Do internal forces of an atom lead it to move, or can an atom only move when an external force is applied to it? For example, if we had a perfect vacuum with the exception of one arbitrary atom, would it move due to internal forces?

Answer (score 4):

The internal forces in any physical body can not result in a net force on the center of mass. At most, they may result in a change in how that body is distributed, which can change factors like angular velocity.

Comment: Just to clarify, as far as I understand the attractive forces between the electron and nucleus of the atom would lead to the atom as a whole vibrating. If that is true, do you mean the atom would effectively remain stationary? But is that guaranteed? Wouldn't it ultimately move in a random direction because of this vibration? Just to clarify what I mean I made an illustration [link](https://i.imgur.com/xBZ7vES.jpeg)

Comment: Imagine yourself floating floating stationary in space. Now imagine wiggling your limbs, doing crunches, and moving about in every way you can imagine. Do any of these movements impart a net force on your center of mass? No. All they can do is change your rotational characteristics.

Comment: That being said, quantum mechanics doesn't like atoms to have exactly defined positions or momenta, so inevitably an observer tracking the atom will have the impression that it is moving about to some degree. Given that your question is regarding forces though, I felt this was beyond the scope of your inquiry.

Comment: Thank you, that analogy was helpful to get your point.